# Why Future extends Handler<AsyncResult> in Vertx?

Tags: java, vert.x

For me a `Future<T>` is an action that will eventually return T, or a provider of an object of type T, while a `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>` is a handler that will need to do something to a result of T, or a consumer of an object of type T. Why does `Future<T>` extends `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>`?

In many functions we have a signature like `EventBus::request(String address, Object message, Handler<AsyncResult<Message<T>>> replyHandler)`, but we can't pass a Future into this function, can we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that Future is an implementation of Deferred Value design pattern, same as JavaScript promises, Kotlin's Deferred, and many others.

To get the result of Deferred value, you often have two options: by providing a callback or by blocking the current thread of execution and waiting until Deferred value either returns a result or an exception.

Since Vert.x, same as JavaScript runtime, operates with a limited number of threads, it opted not to provide a blocking API. So the only way to "unwrap" the future, is to provide it a callback. And anything that's provided a callback called `Handler` in Vert.x. Maybe that's not the best name, and something like "CallbackReceiver" would be better. But that's what we have.

Now let's tackle `AsyncResult<T>` part. Why can't Future be a `Handler` of `T`? That's because, as I mentioned earlier, Deferred value could either return a result, `T`, or an exception, which is `not-T`. For that reason, we wrap those two possible values in `AsyncResult`.

Regarding EventBus API - once inside your callback block, you're already fulfilled the `Future`, so passing `Future` to it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I understand better now. Just one question, you've said that I've already fulfilled the Future inside my callback block. Can't I do something like Future.future().onSuccess(//dosomething).onFailure(//dosomething) and pass it in?

Comment: Technically - yes, you can. Practically - I think it would mostly complicate your code. It's like passing a callback function to another callback function. Works, but confusing.